# How to compare to List<WebElement> in webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate Dual list Box testing. I want to compare the selected values(left side) vs moved values (into right side list). Here is the code.

```
Select allFromListData = new Select(listData);
    // values selection
    allFromListData.selectByIndex(0);
    allFromListData.selectByVisibleText("Helena");
    List<WebElement> selectedList=allFromListData.getAllSelectedOptions();
    //clicking on add button

    for(int i=0;i<selectedList.size();i++)
        System.out.println(selectedList.get(i).getText());
    WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pickList']/div/div[2]/button[1]"));
    addButton.click();

    //Verification of selected content... 
    WebElement toListData=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pickList']/div/div[3]/select"));
    Select allToListData = new Select(toListData);
    List<WebElement> movedData=allToListData.getOptions();
```

Question is how to compare the data between `List<WebElement> selectedList=allFromListData.getAllSelectedOptions();` and `List<WebElement> movedData=allToListData.getOptions();`

Comment: You can compare two lists using for loop . Iterate it till you get data and compare inside the loop

Comment: I tried but it was throwing an exception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you want to compare the list of selected items string not the list of web elements as getOptions() method will return list of web elements. Logic is simple, first take the list of values from the list before and after move. Then sort the both of the list of values and compare/assert for equality as given below.

```
 Select allFromListData = new Select(listData);
    // values selection
    allFromListData.selectByIndex(0);
    allFromListData.selectByVisibleText("Helena");
    List<WebElement> selectedList=allFromListData.getAllSelectedOptions();

    //add selected Items to list
    List<String> lstSelectedItem=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<selectedList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(selectedList.get(i).getText());
        lstSelectedItem.add(selectedList.get(i).getText());
    }

    //clicking on add button
    WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pickList']/div/div[2]/button[1]"));
    addButton.click();

    //Verification of selected content... 
    WebElement toListData=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pickList']/div/div[3]/select"));
    Select allToListData = new Select(toListData);
    List<WebElement> movedData=allToListData.getOptions();

    //add moved Items to list
    List<String> lstMovedItem=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<movedData.size();i++){
        System.out.println(movedData.get(i).getText());
        lstMovedItem.add(movedData.get(i).getText());
    }

    //sort the items
    Collections.sort(lstSelectedItem);
    Collections.sort(lstMovedItem);

    //verify the lists are equal
    Assert.assertEquals(lstSelectedItem, lstMovedItem);
```

Comment: Thanks @Murthi. this works.. Is there any direct API or method to compare two list<webElement>.

Answer (score 1):

You can try intersection() and subtract() methods from **CollectionUtils( java.lang.object)**.

```
subtract(Collection a, Collection b)
```

Returns a new Collection containing a - b.

```
intersection(Collection a, Collection b)
```

Returns a Collection containing the intersection of the given Collections.

Comment: This is needed when you need unique data separately . For comparing there is no need of union and intersection